# Declaring the variables in main function for singly linked list in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am doing this singly linked list program. My problem is when I display the list, it displays nothing. I have reviewed my code and find nothing wrong. I can do this program with no problem when the variables are global. Now I am trying it with my variables are local, in the main function.

- Is it because of my local variables?
- Do I have to return the variables I used in the functions?

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct room                                                            
{                                                                              
    int roomNumber;                                                            

    struct room *nextRoom;                                                     
}room;                                                                         

room *create_room(int val)                                                     
{                                                                              
    room *temp;                                                                
    temp=(room *)malloc(sizeof(room));                                         

    if(temp==NULL)                                                             
    {                                                                          
        printf("create_room error");                                           
        return 0;                                                              
    }                                                                          
    else                                                                       
    {                                                                          
        temp->roomNumber=val;                                                  
        temp->nextRoom=NULL;                                                   

        return temp;                                                           
    }                                                                          

}                                                                                 
void room_insert(room *r,room *last)                                           
{                                                                              
    room *temp;                                                                
    FILE *fp;                                                                  
    int m,f,i;                                                                 
    fp=fopen("room.txt","r");                                                  
    if(fp==NULL)                                                               
    {                                                                          
        printf("room_insert error");                                           
    }                                                                          
    else                                                                       
    {                                                                          
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&m,&f);                                              

        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)                                                      
        {                                                                      
            temp=create_room(i);                                               
            if(r==last && r==NULL)                                             
            {                                                                  
                r=last=temp;                                                   
                r->nextRoom=NULL;                                              
                last->nextRoom=NULL;                                           
            }                                                                  
            else                                                               
            {                                                                  
                last->nextRoom=temp;                                           
                last=temp;                                                     
                last->nextRoom=NULL;                                           
            }                                                                  
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
    fclose(fp);                                                                
}                                                                              

void indisp(room *r)                                                           
{                                                                              

    room *temp;                                                                
    if(r==NULL)                                                                
    {                                                                          
        printf("no node");                                                     
    }                                                                          
    else                                                                       
    {                                                                          
        /*                                                                     
        for(temp=r;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->nextRoom)                             
        {                                                                      
        printf("%d\t",temp->roomNumber);                                       
        }*/                                                                    
        temp=r;                                                                
        while(temp!=NULL)                                                      
        {                                                                      
            printf("%d\t",temp->roomNumber);                                   
            temp=temp->nextRoom;                                               
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
}                                                                              

void main()                                                                    
{                                                                              

    room *r=NULL,*last=NULL;                                                   

    clrscr();                                                                  
    room_insert(r,last);                                                       
    indisp(r);                                                                 

    getch();                                                                   
}
```

The list.txt and reading the file works fine.

Comment: `I have reviewed my code and find nothing wrong`  If you step through it in a debugger, your chances of finding what is wrong are greatly improved.

Comment: Read about passing arguments by reference,

Comment: How do I get a debugger?

Comment: under what platform? in linux or windows or mac?

Comment: I cannot understand why anyone would contemplate anything more complex than 'Hello World' without a debugger.  Also, why are 99.99% of all linked-list questions posted by developers in that 'no debugging' class?

Answer (score 2):

If I pass a variable to a function, normally I would expect that the variable in the calling function wouldn't change:

```
void edit(int x) {
    x = 1;
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    edit(x);
    assert(x == 5);
}
```

This is also true with pointers:

```
void edit(int *x) {
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
    int *x = NULL;
    edit(x);
    assert(x == NULL);
}
```

If I want to modify a variable, I need to pass a pointer to that variable:

```
void edit(int *x) {
    *x = 1;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    edit(&x);
    assert(x == 1);
}
```

Likewise, if I want to modify a pointer, I need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void edit(int **x) {
    *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **x = 1;
}

int main() {
    int *x = NULL;
    edit(&x);
    assert(x);
    assert(*x == 1);
}
```

Your code doesn't do this. So in your `main()`, `r` and `last` will always point to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the a copy of the variable `r` in `room_insert`. That does not change the value in the calling function, `main`. Change `room_insert` to return the head of the list to `main`.

```
room* room_insert()
{
   room* r = NULL;
   room* last = NULL;

   // Keep the rest of your code
   // ....

   return r;
}
```

Change the call in `main` to:

```
r = room_insert();
```

Answer (score 1):

All variables in C are passed to the function using what is known as `pass by value`. When you pass a pointer as an argument to a function, the value of the pointer (ie. the address it points to) is copied to the function's parameter, a new variable. If you modify this variable, then it will not affect the passed pointer in the caller function, since they are different variables that exist in each function's stack.

Since you want to modify the pointer here, pass a pointer to the pointer (`&r`). Then in the called function, assign new value to its dereferenced state, something in the lines of `*r = last;`